# Problem extracting a specific table from a PDF-page with multiple tables. (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, python-camelot, pdf-extraction

this is my first time posting here on stack overflow because I really have nowhere else to turn.

My problem is extracting a specific table from a PDF-file containing multiple tables, and converting that specific table to a dataframe.

[image of PDF-page in question:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEnuL.png)

In the image, you can see the tables highlighted in red and a specific table highlighted in green. I want only the green table, not the other ones.

I have been trying to do this using Camelot.
Basically:

```
tables_dataframe = camelot.read_pdf(PDF_file, pages=page, flavor='stream')
table = tables_dataframe[0] 
df_table = table.df
```

This however is not optimal, since it takes all the content of that PDF-page (see image) and makes a mashed dataframe that gets too messy.

Now one could go about cleaning up the dataframe specifically... but I feel it is much more efficient to just generate the desired dataframe from the start.

All help is appreciated. How can I generalize a code that can specifically target the tables I want in a situation where there are multiple tables on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

In order to target a specific table on the page of a pdf file you can you the `table_regions` parameter of `read_pdf()` function. Here is an example according to [Camelot docs](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#specify-table-regions):

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf('table_regions.pdf', table_regions=['170,370,560,270'])
```

You will need to play around with the values to get the right table.

Comment: Sure, that is a way to do it. In my case, since every PDF page is different, it would require me manually to adjust the table regions for each individual page, right?

Comment: If there's no way to automate it, then yes.